# Wrong value when using First_Value function in Mysql

Tags: mysql, function, partition

I need to prepare a report based on this table, which I can only read:

[image]

The idea is to have the last value for each observation based on higher activity identification.  For instance, value for Observation 10 corresponds to activity number 19.

[image]

So far, this is my code:

```
select 
first_value(text) over (partition by employee order by case when observation = 10 then activity else 0 end desc) as "Obs 10",
first_value(number) over (partition by employee order by case when observation = 20 then activity else 0 end desc) as "Obs 20",
first_value(dropdown) over (partition by employee order by case when observation = 40 then activity else 0 end desc) as "Obs 40"
-- the same for the rest of the observations
from employee_proc
```

However, the employee could be associated with other Observations that could be no registered at the moment of the execution of the query.

If I include this piece of code for this employee:

```
...
first_value(text) over (partition by employee order by case when observation = 120 then activity else 0 end desc) as "Obs 120",
...
```

I'm getting a wrong value instead of null (given that the observation has not been registered for him yet).

How can I avoid getting this kind of result?. Is there another way to get the final result, another more optimized?

Regards.

Comment: `MySQL 10.3.8` ?? Do you perhaps mean `mariaDB 10.3.8` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result you have shown in your question could be achieved more efficiently via query below:

```
create temporary table max_activity
select observation,max(activity) from employee_proc group by 1;


select employee,
activity,
MAX(IF(observation = 10, ifnull(TEXT_,ifnull(date_in,ifnull(number,dropdown))),NULL)) AS Obs10,
MAX(IF(observation = 20, ifnull(TEXT_,ifnull(date_in,ifnull(number,dropdown))),NULL)) AS Obs20,
MAX(IF(observation = 30, ifnull(TEXT_,ifnull(date_in,ifnull(number,dropdown))),NULL)) AS Obs30,
MAX(IF(observation = 40, ifnull(TEXT_,ifnull(date_in,ifnull(number,dropdown))),NULL)) AS Obs40,
MAX(IF(observation = 50, ifnull(TEXT_,ifnull(date_in,ifnull(number,dropdown))),NULL)) AS Obs50,
MAX(IF(observation = 60, ifnull(TEXT_,ifnull(date_in,ifnull(number,dropdown))),NULL)) AS Obs60,
MAX(IF(observation = 70, ifnull(TEXT_,ifnull(date_in,ifnull(number,dropdown))),NULL)) AS Obs70,
MAX(IF(observation = 80, ifnull(TEXT_,ifnull(date_in,ifnull(number,dropdown))),NULL)) AS Obs80,
MAX(IF(observation = 90, ifnull(TEXT_,ifnull(date_in,ifnull(number,dropdown))),NULL)) AS Obs90,
MAX(IF(observation = 100, ifnull(TEXT_,ifnull(date_in,ifnull(number,dropdown))),NULL)) AS Obs100,
MAX(IF(observation = 110, ifnull(TEXT_,ifnull(date_in,ifnull(number,dropdown))),NULL)) AS Obs110
from employee_proc
inner join max_activity
on employee_proc.activity = max_activity.activity
group by 1,2;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Solomon, it was very usefull.

Comment: If I have answered your question. Can you please mark it answered? You are welcome :) @d2907